# is it wise to store User ID in MySQL and related time series (ecg) data in mongodb? The association is such that user has many ECGs

Tags: mysql, mongodb

The user table is used for authentication. While it is seen that it is efficient to store time series data in mongodb.

I expect moving the user table to mongodb is an alternative. Is maintaining a foreign key relations across database a bad design?

Comment: It is a common design.  Good or bad really depends on the goals and implementation.